# Which file IDEA uses to display the name of Android project?

Tags: intellij-idea

Which file in Android project does IDEA use to display project name in Recent Projects list?

[image]

If I want to change display name of my 8th project to "My changed project", which file should I edit? Is this done manually editing a certain file or can be done in a faster way via Ctrl+F6?

I am asking this as renaming module will not change display name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the [project format](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project.html), IDEA uses either the .ipr file (its name, specifically) or some file buried under the .idea directory apparently.

Anyway, to change the project (display) name:

### Projects using the newer directory-based format

<sup>(If you're not sure which format your project is using, try this first.)</sup>

Don't edit any file; instead, open the **Project Structure** dialog (Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S or ⌘;), and under General Settings for Project, change Project name.

[image]

### Projects using the older file-based format

Find the main project settings file with **.ipr** extension, in your case `LibraryTest.ipr`, and simply rename that. Also rename the accompanying **.iws** file.

(NB: Close the project before doing this. Also, if there's an .iml module file with the same name, leave that alone. If you want to change names of modules, do that through Project Structure settings.)

The project will first disappear from the Recent Projects list; you'll have to use "Open Project" and find the newly renamed .ipr file to open it.

Comment: Funny but my screen does not look like yours. I cannot change this and I'm using IDEA 11.1. There is not such field. Do you want me to show you a screenshot?

Comment: @sandalone: it could be that the field only appears for projects using the newer [*directory-based* format](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project.html). I'm on IDEA 10.5, but don't see it either for a project using *file-based* format. I'm investigating how to change the name in that case...

Comment: @sandalone: Btw, if you ever want to convert from file-based to directory-based format, see [this instruction](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/converting-project-into-directory-based-format.html); it's very simple.

Comment: And this only moves references from ipr/iws to .idea folder? I am reluctant to do this in huge projects.

Comment: @sandalone: I don't know intimately what the conversion does, but I have used it in the past and am fairly confident that it *works*, i.e. you don't lose anything. If unsure, you can 1) try with smaller project first, 2) take backups or 3) just keep using the file-based format... Did renaming the files work for you?

Comment: Yes, I did that in the past already but I was wondering if there is a more proper way to do renaming.

Comment: Ok, nice. For file-based projects, this is the proper (and only) way, it seems. (If you have further doubts about the format conversion, you could post a new question about that.)